# Different syntax variations when defining delegates in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

I don't get to do as much C# as I would like at work, and am trying to keep my skills polished. I've come up with the following ways to define a delegate (although the last one is kind of cheating). Have I missed any syntax variants?

```
public delegate bool mytest(string input);

public static mytest delegateProperty { get; set; }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    delegateProperty = delegate { return true; };

    delegateProperty = delegate(string myInput) { return true; };

    delegateProperty = new mytest(delegate(string myInput) { return true; });

    delegateProperty = (myInput) => { return true; };

    delegateProperty = myInput => { return true; };

    var delegateProperty2 = new Func<string, bool>(new mytest(delegate(string bob) { return true;}));
}
```

Comment: `delegateProperty = (string myInput) => { return true; };`

Comment: `delegateProperty = (string myInput) => { return true; };`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I win by 4 seconds :woot:

Comment: @280Z28 You beat me to it in 4 seconds.. :( I was removing spaces and adding back ticks.

Comment: But you should make it into an answer.

Comment: Also `myInput => true;` Of course, if you have a compatible method, say MyMethod: `delegateProperty = MyMethod;` and `delegateProperty = new mytest(MyMethod);`

Comment: Just look up the language specs to see a formal definition for the valid syntax of declaring a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

I can see atleast three variants you missed.

```
delegateProperty = (string myInput) => { return true; };

delegateProperty = SomeCompatibleMethod;

delegateProperty = new mytest(SomeCompatibleMethod);
```

And from @ mikez

```
delegateProperty  = myInput => true;
```